# SparkUI Executor tab active is 1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, driver, executor

Why do i only see the driver in the executor tab of sparkUI and not the executors as well ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because spark runs in `local[*]` mode. It runs spark locally with as many `worker threads` as logical cores on your machine.

I cannot add a comment.
The number of CPUs occupied by the Driver --`Cores` column is consistent with the number of your logical CPUs.

Comment: There are 8 logical core in my machine.
wmic cpu get NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors
4              8